# Is cursing allowed in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram

Can a Muslim swear? By "swear" I mean can he say stuff like, (pardon me): f*** or godda*mn? Please pay attention that I just mentioned the words and didn't direct them towards a thing or a person. Is it still wrong?
Thank you so much
May Allah bless you.

Comment: Look up the words Wayl, Wayh, (ثَكِلَتْكَ أُمُّكَ, Let your mother bereave you!).. All languages has some form of swearing words. You will find these in the ahadith

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend to choose the best vocabularies [17:53](https://quran.com/17/53)

> Tell my worshiper to speak nice , Devil removes (relation) between them
>   , Devil is obvious enemy for Human.

I wan to say something "God ensure that strengthening relationships is the victory against devil " So victory Allah and he will victory you .

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking your time to learn more about our site and model by taking our 2 min. [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that it is haraam , per se, but I believe it is discouraged. Foul language is not becoming of a Muslim , or of anyone in general. Also, I have been taught that if one swears while fasting, while it does not break the fast, it makes it makrooh.

Comment: Please provide evidence for your claim why you believe it is not haram

Comment: Look at it this way, your mouth recites the Quran, yes? Why on earth would you want to utter such words from the same mouth? Also find and listen to Mufti Menk's talks on youtube too.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. I strongly recommend you to read [answer] to learn what we expect an answer here to look like. To learn more about our site and model i further invite you to take our [tour] and check our [help]. Now to your claim: A fast can't be makrooh unless the occasion you fast on is makrooh like on friday, saturday or sunnday (for some schools of fiqh). What you may mean is the fast is valid but you may not gain any (or less) rewards for it.

Comment: Look up the words Wayl, Wayh, (ثَكِلَتْكَ أُمُّكَ, Let your mother bereave you!).. All languages has some form of swearing words. You will find these in the ahadith

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's haram but I do know Prophet Muhammad (S.A.W) (pbuh) said that, and I paraphrase, that most of the sins of a believer are from his mouth. This could be meaning te use of bad words.

Answer (score 0):

I used to swear a lot years ago. But then I remembered that the Prophet Mohammed (PBUH) said that most of the sins come from the tounge. So I stopped swearing in any form of light or heavy cussing. So I think you should not cuss too since I feel that I became a better person afterwards. If you get mad, just try to calm down. If you can't hold it then just go to a room alone or take a pillow to lower the sound of the scream.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's absolutely Haram, because cussing is a NO NO, and Muslims that cuss are not practicing muslims or that's been to a bad path or parents that cuss, so my suggestion is if you cuss say Authubilliah min a shaytan E regeem